# Create a report from frequency

Tags: python

How do you convert a frequency dictionary to a report dictionary?

from... `[('a': 2), ('b':6), ('cd':1), ('g':9)]`

to...

```
a 2  
b 6  
cd 1  
g 9
```

I used this to create the frequency dictionary...

```
openfile = open(filename, 'r')
x = openfile.read()
uplist = p.split()
wc = {}
for word in uplist:
    if word in wc.keys():
        wc[word] +=1
    else:
        wc[word] = 1

return wc.items()
```

Now, I have to create a report function.

Comment: You can skip most of this code by using `wc = collections.Counter(uplist)`

Answer (score 1):

Just loop and print:

```
for item, freq in items:
    print(item, freq)
```

Strictly speaking, because you return `wc.items()`, you do not have a dictionary but a list of tuples instead.